# How to perform ajax post request to get some values from the last row of?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json, ajax

Hi I was asked to get some data from the last row in the database using `ajax post` request.
I have two files which are **PHP** scrip which is used to connect to the database and get all the data and convert the data to `json` format. I performed ajax post to PHP script to get all data. I want to modify the ajax post to request an additional data from the last row of the tables in database.

For example, in `student` table, there are 10 rows of data in database. I want to get data from the last row.  My question is how to get values from the last row in the database..
Requirement: do not modify the `SQL` code as I need all the data and additionally the last row of data.
I do not want this code data[9]['student_name'];

here is my code below...
html file

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Cesium-1.34/ThirdParty/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<div id="result"</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
showData();
function showData()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "student.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "how to request data from the last row of the database????
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

php script

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','netwitness') or die ("Could not connect database");
$db = mysqli_select_db($conn,'abdpractice') or die ('Could not select database');

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student");
$json_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $json_array[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json_array);
?>
```

My question is how to get data from the last row of database?

Requirement: do not modify the SQL code as I only want to modify the ajax post. Please help me. This is for my project.

Comment: If you won't change the request neither the query - which will keep bring all data - you have to get the last row in javascript, e.g. `data[data.length - 1]`.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown hi erm i do not understand on what are u saying.. where i am supposed to implement that code????

Comment: is this where i am supposed to implement that code??? $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "student.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data[data.length-1]

Answer (score 0):

Change the PHP code as follows.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','netwitness') or die ("Could not connect database");
$db = mysqli_select_db($conn,'abdpractice') or die ('Could not select database');

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student");
$json_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $json_array[] = $row;
}
$limit = count($json_array);
echo json_encode($json_array[$limit-1]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. It seems you want to send a param to PHP the only the last row, but I'm not sure. If that's true, you can do what @Rossi proposed adding a parameter like:

```
data: {
    lastOnly: true
}
```

And at the end of the script:

```
if (!isset($_POST["lastOnly"])) {
    echo json_encode($json_array);
} else {
    echo json_encode($json_array[count($json_array)-1]);
}
```

---

But, if still wants to get all data from back-end but deal with the last row in your javascript, you can do what i've said in the comments:

```
success: function(data) {
    var lastRow = data[data.length - 1];
}
```

**UPDATE:** To get only one field.

1. You can send back only one value and your `data` will receive a string instead of a json object:

   ```
   echo $json_array["student_name"];
   ```
2. You can get the the property from your json object:

   ```
   data.student_name
   ```

Comment: HI that is the code i am looking for... but how i am suposed to get only the student _name from the last row as i do not want other data such as student religion student gender and student age